# proceeding after the correct answer is given

Tags: python

Hello I needed help with my code. After asking the user if they want to begin or not the answer yes should start the 5 second count down and present the first question how do i do this?
And one final thing is when i run the program as it is even when i give the correct answer which is yes it loops back to are you ready.

```
import random

import sys

import os

print('What is your name?')

name = raw_input()

sys.stdin.readline()

print "Hello!",name

print('I will be asking a series of true of false uqestions, answer with 
either true or false')

def introduction():

    while True:

        print('Shall we begin?')

        ans = raw_input()

        if ans == 'yes':

            print('The questions will begin in 5 seconds')

        else:

            print('Please return when you are ready')

introduction()
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know how to do that i don't have enough time sorry

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40963822/edit), copy the code from your editor, paste it into the question, select the block of code, and format it as code by pressing the Ctrl+K (Command+K on Mac). It is absolutely essential you do this if you want our help because indentation is crucial in python.

Comment: @theman: If you do not have enough time to ask a question cleanly, then definitely we do not have enough time to answer it

Answer (score 0):

To do a five second count down in python `import time` and then do `time.sleep(5)`
To ask a question do `question_answer = raw_input("Insert Question 1 here")`
After you say "yes", the code will print " The questions will begin in five seconds" and then will revert back to the infinite while loop because it is `while True:` and that will not end. If you will want it to end do something like `x = True` and then `while x:` as that means you can change it later on. Finally I recommend using `ans.lower()` so that inputs of "Yes" will also work.

Also the `sys.stdin.readline()`is redundant code.

Comment: @theman - I am pretty sure that covers everything in your question- any other questions?

Answer (score 0):

I thought my other answer was pretty clear but this is the code from your question with parts you have requested added in- enjoy:

```
import random

import time

print('What is your name?')

name = raw_input()

print("Hello!",name)

print('I will be asking a series of true of false questions, answer with 
either true or false')

def introduction():
    x = True
    while x:

        print('Shall we begin?')

        ans = raw_input()

        if ans.lower() == 'yes':

            print('The questions will begin in 5 seconds')
            time.sleep(5)
            birthday = raw_input("When is your birthday?")

        else:

            print('Please return when you are ready')

introduction()
```